# Angular Toggle not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to convert the following into an Angular approach and I am stuck:

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container">             
            <embed src="www.example.com/pdf1" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf">
            <embed src="www.example.com/pdf2" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf2">  
</div>

<div class="container">
    <button class="btn-info" onclick="toggle('myPdf2')" type="button">Toggle PDF</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle(target) {
            var curVal = document.getElementById(target).style.visibility;
            document.getElementById(target).style.visibility = (curVal === 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
};
```

Basically it is a toggle, that makes one of the pdf's appear and disappear.

I was suggested to take the following angular approach:

```
 <button ng-click="isShown = isShown ? false : true" type="button">Toggle</button>
              <div id="container" class="container">    
               <embed src="www.example.com/pdf1" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf"> 
               <embed ng-show="isShown" src="www.example.com/pdf2" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf2"> 
             </div>
```

The Angular approach is not working for me for some reason.

Comment: I have tested. Your code working fine in my browser.I have tried with 2 pdf sources. `http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CAT24AA01-D.PDF` and `http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CAT24C03-D.PDF`. It takes time to load. I think your pdfs take much time to load

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ng-show` directive on both PDFs. Also `isShown = isShown?false:true` can be simplified to `isShown = !isShown`

Try this:

```
<html ng-app>
<body ng-controller="mianController">
    <button ng-click="isShown = !isShown" type="button">Toggle</button>
    <div id="container" class="container">    
        <embed ng-show="!isShown" src="www.example.com/pdf1" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf"> 
        <embed ng-show="isShown" src="www.example.com/pdf2" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf2"> 
    </div>
<body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module([]).controller('mainController', function($scope){});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried this, but still have had no luck with it.

Comment: @arjwolf Can you show more of your code ? Have you properly setup the angular app and defined a controller ?

Comment: `<html ng-app>
<body ng-controller="mianController">
    <button ng-click="isShown = !isShown" type="button">Toggle</button>
    <div id="container" class="container">    
        <embed ng-show="!isShown" src="http://web.mit.edu/fintel/fintel-2000-whatever.pdf" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf"> 
        <embed ng-show="isShown" src="http://www.american.edu/cas/lfs/faculty-docs/upload/Baron-MLA-Whatever.pdf" width="500" height="500" type='application/pdf' id="myPdf2"> 
    </div>
<body>
</html>`

Comment: `angular.module([]).controller('mianController', function($scope){});`

Comment: I get error saying the `mianController` is undefined

Comment: @arjwolf you have to create a JavaScript file, reference it in the HTML file and add that code (`angular.module([]).controller('mainController', function($scope){});`) to it.